# If window.location ends with specified value via variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, window.location

The jQuery below doesn't work but when the `var link` is equal to `file:///C:/Users/USER/Desktop/test%20page/Home.html` it does so is there a jquery where IF the `window.location.href;` ends with the specified variable such as `var link ="/Home.html";` then execute javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var winloc = window.location.href; // file:///C:/Users/USER/Desktop/test%20page/Home.html
var link = "/Home.html";
if(winloc==link){
$('ul li a').remove();
}
});
<ul>
<li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It looks like you want to hide the link for the page you're currently on? This might be better handled server-side...

Comment: also, `window.location.pathname` will probably give you what you need (the relative path without all the `file://` or `http://` junk on it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `lastIndexOf` and get the last part of the url which is `/Home.html` in you case and check it with `link` var.

See my [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qbcpm/1/).

Code below,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var winloc = "file:///C:/Users/USER/Desktop/test%20page/Home.html";
    var link = "/Home.html";
    winloc = winloc.substring (winloc.lastIndexOf("/"));
    if (winloc == link) {
        $('ul li a').remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: Nice you took Kolink's answer and made it more user friendly, and got the credit for it, +1

Answer (score 0):

```
if( winloc.substr(winloc.length-link.length) == link) {
    $('ul li a').remove();
}
```

Comment: This is in the right direction, but too 'pseudo-cody' to be understood by novices

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one liner which I think is what Jivings meant to write. I think it's more elegant than the accepted solution http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/qbcpm/10/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var winloc = "file:///C:/Users/USER/Desktop/test%20page/Home.html";
    // The regular expression below looks for Home.html at the end of a string 
    if (/Home\.html$/.test(winloc)) {
        $('ul li a').remove();
    }
});
```